# Capturing failure details to file using ruby test/unit

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I'm writing a quick test using the test/unit gem, and want to write error/failure details to a file. In the teardown section I'm using the @test_passed variable to know when there's a failure, and then I write to a file, but I can't seem to find the proper variable to dump out the method that failed or any failure details.

I really only want to capture the errors. It seems like it should be fairly simple. Anyone know what variables test/unit is using to store the error details?

Below is an example how I'm trying to dump out the errors:

```
require "test/unit"

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
  end

  def teardown
    if @test_passed then
      puts "no errors"
    else
      File.open("errors.txt", "a+") do |f|
        f.puts "Error in #{what_is_the_variable_for_the_method_name}"
        f.puts "#{variable_with_error_details_like_expecting_this_but_got_that}"
      end
    end
  end

  def test_fail
    a = 9
    assert_equal(a, 10)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The source files of the `Test::Unit` framework are installed on your system. Look for testcase.rb.

The results are stored in a `@_result` member.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the documentation. I had tried outputting @_result as well as @internal_data, but they always seem to be empty. Either I'm catching them before they are populated, or I'm just doing it wrong. My bet is that I'm doing it wrong.